# Замена массива в многомерном массиве

Tags: php

Подскажите как проще сделать замену массивов в многомерном массиве.

Имеется конфиг из файла в формате `JSON`,декодирую его и на выходе получаю вот такой массив.

```
  Array
    (
        [name] => Tables conf
        [databases] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => DB1
                        [tables] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => table1
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => table2
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => table3
                                    )

                            )

                    )
            ) 
)
```

А так же имеется новый конфиг вида:

```
Array
(
    [databases] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => DB1
                    [tables] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [tbl_name] => table1
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [tbl_name] => table2
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [tbl_name] => table3
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => DB2
                    [tables] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [tbl_name] => table2
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [tbl_name] => table3
                                )

                        )

                )
         )
)
```

Как можно проще внедрить новый конфиг в старый при этом не перезаписывая весь старый, а только изменить какой то массив по ключу иди добавить новый, то есть весь `DB1` к примеру заменить на новый `DB1` или добавить `DB2`.

Попробовал вот такой вариант,работает,хотелось бы узнать как можно сделать проще.

```
$config = $_POST['config'];
            $filteredConfig = array_filter($config['databases'], function($val, $key){
                return !empty($val['tables']);
            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

            $fileConfig = file_get_contents('conf/tables_config_vars.json');
            $fileConfig = json_decode($fileConfig, true);

            foreach($fileConfig['databases'] as $key => $val){

                foreach($filteredConfig as $confKey => $confVal){
                    if($val['name'] == $confVal['name']){
                        unset($fileConfig['databases'][$key]);
                        $fileConfig['databases'][] = $confVal;

                    } 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
function mergeConfig(array &$config, array $addConfig)
{
    foreach ($addConfig as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($config[$key]) && is_array($config[$key])) {
            is_array($value)
                ? $this->mergeConfig($config[$key], $value)
                : array_push($config[$key], $value);
        } else {
            $config[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

где $config - базовый и результирующий конфиг, к которому нужно подлить другой; $addConfig - конфиг, который нужно добавить